# How can I import images into containerd？

Tags: containerd, skopeo

I imported an image by using ctr image import alpine.tar but I use ctr images ls return is empty

[image: 1]

first i use skopeo copy docker://docker.io/library/alpine:latest docker-archive:alpine.tar to get the tar

I wish I could import this image into containerd

Comment: Does ti show up when using the crictl command?  Example:

    crictl -r unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock images

Comment: Also, have you looked in all of the namepaces.  You can list them via: "ctr namespaces list".  Try running: "ctr -n k8s.io images ls|grep TheImageName".

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong with the tar I typed out

Answer (score 0):

you can add `--additional-tag` to copy.

```
skopeo copy --additional-tag alpine:latest docker://docker.io/library/alpine:latest docker-archive:alpine.tar
```

then import this image.

```
ctr image import alpine.tar
```